# From a payment platform redirecting to display receipt on another page doesn't occur

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been using response.redirect for ages but on that opportunity, it doesn't work as expected.

The situation is simple I have got a form, Pay40.aspx, where the user click on apay button, the payment is processed and I am getting back the information from the server. In my process, I want to redirect to another page to display a receipt. But it doesn't. Instead of being redirected to PayFinal.aspx I am seeing in the address Pay40.aspx/PayFinal.aspx?Payment=OK&Order=OC00011 . I tried doing a server.transfer but got the same issue

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)

    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim RandomGenerator As New Random()
        txtSession.Text = RandomGenerator.Next(999999999).ToString()
    End If

    If InStr(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "NormalReturn") > 0 Then
        Dim result = (New Transaction()).Commit(Request("token_ws"))
 
        If result.ResponseCode.ToString = 0 And result.Status.ToString = "AUTHORIZED" Then
            Response.Redirect("PayFinal.aspx?Payment=OK&Order=" & result.BuyOrder.ToString)
            Response.End()
        Else
            Response.Redirect("PayFinal.aspx?Payment=KO&Order=" & result.BuyOrder.ToString)
            Response.End()
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPay.Click


    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)

    Dim vHttpHost As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST").ToString()
    Dim vSelfURL As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("URL").ToString()
    Dim sample_baseurl As String = "http://" + vHttpHost + vSelfURL + "/NormalReturn"

    Dim tx = New Transaction(New Options(IntegrationCommerceCodes.WEBPAY_PLUS, IntegrationApiKeys.WEBPAY, WebpayIntegrationType.Test))
    Dim response = tx.Create(txtOrder.Text, txtSession.Text, txtAmount.Text, sample_baseurl)
    Dim vAction As String = IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("action")), HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("action"), "init")

    Dim myremotepost As cRemotePost = New cRemotePost
    myremotepost.Url = response.Url
    myremotepost.Add("token_ws", response.Token)
    myremotepost.Post()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue. It was coming from this line of code

```
  Dim sample_baseurl As String = "http://" + vHttpHost + vSelfURL + "/NormalReturn"
```

By changing it to

```
  Dim sample_baseurl As String = "http://" + vHttpHost + vSelfURL
```

And changing the Page_Load accordingly solved it. My mistake.